# Let's get critical: Nov 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Physical Fitness Stack Exchange](http://fitness.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: I rated a lot of questions as "needs improvement" almost solely because there was only one answer.

Comment: IMO the big shortcoming of the site right now is that every question seems to attract half a dozen answers, all of them expressing opinions and none of them giving any evidence for those opinions.

Comment: @BenCrowell Could you point to some examples?

Comment: @DaveLiepmann: a typical example: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/938/how-to-run-without-damaging-your-feet-knees-or-hips

Comment: @BenCrowell Ivo's answer (and yours) both include good evidence. While I'm a fan of evidence-based answers, I'm not a fan of *requiring* peer-reviewed evidence. Sports science (especially w/r/t injuries) is difficult and not generally terribly useful. For instance, the fact that there aren't any studies on the intersection of yoga and running doesn't make Doug's answer bad. Yoga addresses joint issues, running injuries involve joint issues, it's reasonable advice to give despite not being peer-reviewed medicine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Is it better to relax or strech a "strained" muscle?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/14069/is-it-better-to-relax-or-strech-a-strained-muscle)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [What are the merits of cycling vs running for a beginner?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/14063/what-are-the-merits-of-cycling-vs-running-for-a-beginner)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [At what speed should I run?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/14023/at-what-speed-should-i-run)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Body movement during the seated cable row](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/14120/body-movement-during-the-seated-cable-row)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Are so-called "burst workouts" effective for weight loss?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/13981/are-so-called-burst-workouts-effective-for-weight-loss)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [relationship between power and body fat](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/14253/relationship-between-power-and-body-fat)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [What are good home-exercises for a 7-year-old swimmer to increase stamina, endurance and GPP?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/14160/what-are-good-home-exercises-for-a-7-year-old-swimmer-to-increase-stamina-endur)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Upper-body cardio](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/14001/upper-body-cardio)

  **Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [How to distinguish acetone and ammonia odor after running?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/14091/how-to-distinguish-acetone-and-ammonia-odor-after-running)

  **Net Score: -6** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 6)

---

- [Calluses under big toe](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/14188/calluses-under-big-toe)

  **Net Score: -8** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 8)

---